# Petición AJAX desde Chrome 'request doesn't pass access control check: 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

Tags: jquery, ajax, nodejs, express, google-chrome

Estoy teniendo un problema con una petición **AJAX** desde el navegador **Chrome** el cual no me había pasado nunca. Estoy requiriendo datos de la **API** de **Dark Sky** y me aparece este mensaje:

***Utilizo NodeJS con express***

*localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.darksky.net/forecast/bcce7da12ae098129b6c69b207e89ecb/28.1235459,-15.4362574. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3030' is therefore not allowed access.*

1. Ya he utilizado las flags --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
2. He usado el proxy CORS de crossoriginme.com
3. He customizado el header en la peticion AJAX que hize con jQuery
4. En codepen.io me funciona perfectamente y puedo comunicarme sin problemas

Y nada, que no me quiere entregar los datos, aquí debajo pongo el código:

**Configuración express: **

```
   const express = require('express')
   const app = express();

let port = process.env.PORT || 3030;

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next()
})

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
   response.render('index')
 })

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

**Archivo JS**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

function getLocation() {
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      fetchWeatherData(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
    }, function(error) {
      //Aqui manejo los errores
    })
  } else {
         //Pendiente aun
   }
}

function fetchWeatherData(latitude, longitude) {
  let URL = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/bcce7da12ae098129b6c69b207e89ecb/${latitude},${longitude}`
  $.ajax(URL, {
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response.data)
    }
  })

}

getLocation()
```

Uso gulp + browserify + babelify para hacer el bundle

Comment: Acabo de solucionarlo ahora mismo, justo en la función de success, pensaba que para acceder al main body del objeto JSON debia adjuntarle .data pero no es así y ahora al solo hacer el console.log(response) si me hace la petición correctamente y obtengo el JSON. Aun así no entiendo porque simplemente no obtuve un statusCode 404 de la petición

Comment: No te recomiendo activar la bandera para desactivar la [política de seguridad del navegador para peticiones de dominio cruzado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). En su lugar, simplemente pudiste establecer CORS en un middleware de Express. Eso hubiese sido suficiente.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, ya he reactivado la política de seguridad del navegador y hago la petición cambiando el dataType a 'jsonp' y todo funciona correctamente, gracias por las respuestas!